# Restrict multiple dates in date picker

Tags: angular, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have a calendar and I want certanin dates to be disabled, am using https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

in html i have this

```
<p-calendar formControlName="date"  [inline]="true" [disabledDates]="restictedBookingDates"  [minDate]="minimumDate" tabindex="0" readonlyInput="true">
                <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
                    <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (date.day ==10) ? '#7cc67c' : 'inherit'}"   style="border-radius:50%">{{date.day}}</span>
                </ng-template>
            </p-calendar>
```

in compo.ts i have

```
 restictedBookingDates: Array<Date>; 

 ngOnInit() {
    const today = new Date();
    const invalidDate = new Date();
    invalidDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    this.restictedBookingDates = [today, invalidDate];
  }
```

This restrict only todays date, I want to be able to restrict multiple dates eg

```
var restictedBookingDates= ["7-15-2018", "7-23-2018", "7-23-2018"];
```

what do I need to change in my code to acomplish what I want?

Comment: As per the last question you asked, you will need to create a date object representing the date you want to restrict, for example `new Date(2018, 06, 28)` will create a date representing the 28th of July 2018, as the month is 0 based.

Comment: but i want multiple dates, Date(2018, 06, 28, 2018, 06, 29)  i get error when passing multiple dates to restrict it ,

Comment: Create separate Date objects, and push them into a single array

Comment: I tried diffent ways bro nothing works if you know can you help? what exactly I need to do , nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of your restricted dates, like so:

```
restrictedBookingDates = [
    new Date(2018, 6, 23),
    new Date(2018, 6, 17)
];
```

This would restrict bookings on the 23rd and 17th of July. Please note that the month options is zero based, so 6 represents July.

[Here is a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-dkhxyj?file=app/app.component.ts)